# Unwanted duplicate kivy widget

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I only want one ball widget displayed bouncing around on the screen. However two ball widget's are displayed, one moving and the other stationary positioned in the center of the screen. This is my python code:

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, NumericProperty, ReferenceListProperty
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.vector import Vector
from kivy.clock import Clock


refresh_rate = 1/60

Builder.load_file("./balls.kv")


class Balls(Widget):

    vx = NumericProperty(0)
    vy = NumericProperty(0)

    velocity = ReferenceListProperty(vx,vy)

    def move(self):
        self.pos = Vector(self.velocity) + self.pos


class BallsLogic(Widget):

    ball = ObjectProperty(None)

    def start(self):
        self.ball.velocity = 10, -3

    def update(self, dt):

        self.ball.move()

        if self.ball.y < self.y or self.ball.top > self.top:
            self.ball.vy *= -1

        if self.ball.x < self.x or self.ball.right > self.right:
            self.ball.vx *= -1


class BallsApp(App):

    def build(self):
        bl = BallsLogic()
        bl.start()
        Clock.schedule_interval(bl.update, refresh_rate)
        return bl


if __name__ == "__main__":
    BallsApp().run()
```

With the accompanying kv file:

```
#kivy 1.0.9

<Balls>
    size:50,50
    canvas:
        Ellipse:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos

<BallsLogic>
    ball: ball
    Balls:
        center: self.parent.center
        id: ball
```

I've tried re-writing the program to see where I may have gone wrong. I notice the issue when I implement the move method. One ball widget stay's in place, and the other zooms across the screen. I only want one ball widget bouncing around, and I can't figure out where the stationary one is coming from or why it isn't effected by the update or move methods.

Comment: strange, for me the code does not even run.  I suggest renaming your kivy file from balls.kv to something else because Kivy does some behind the scenes magic to load a file that matches your app name.  You might be double-loading it.  fwiw, I get the error "add_widget() can be used only with instances of the Widget class"  on the "bl = BallsLogic()" line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kivy will automatically load a properly named `kv` file, see the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable-2.0.0/api-kivy.app.html#kivy.app.App.load_kv). In your case, a `kv` file with the name `balls.kv` will automatically be loaded. Also, the code:

```
Builder.load_file("./balls.kv")
```

loads the same file. This results in the `balls.kv` file being loaded twice, and two `Balls` widgets being added to the `BallsLogic` widget. The fix is to simply remove the above line of code so that the `balls.kv` file only gets loaded once.

Comment: This Worked. I completely over looked this as I've always used the Builder class to load my kv files but wouldn't include the .kv file extension in the name of my kv file. But with the file extension, and my app class having the same name as my file, and using the Builder class as you pointed out load's it twice. If I remove the file extension in my kv file and the Builder string it only loads one file and works as intended.